# java clone a map which contains a nested map

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>> ();
```

I wanna clone this map, I did like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> newMap =  (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) ((HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>) map).clone();
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(map.get("myKey1").get("myKey2"));
newMap.get("myKey1").put("myKey2","testValue"); 
System.out.println(map.get("myKey1").get("myKey2"));
System.out.println(newMap.get("myKey1").get("myKey2"));
```

I get this output:

`map.get("myKey1").get("myKey2")`: OldValue

`map.get("myKey1").get("myKey2")`: testValue

`newMap.get("myKey1").get("myKey2")`: testValue

It's strange when getting `map.get("myKey1").get("myKey2") = testValue` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I did like this:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> newMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();   
    for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        newMap.put(entry.getKey(),  (Map<String, String>) ((HashMap<String, String>) map.get(entry.getKey())).clone());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#clone()

> Returns a shallow copy of this HashMap instance: the keys and values
>   themselves are not cloned.

ANSWER: You must iterate through any type of collection you want to copy and clone individual elements.

SUGGESTION: Java doesn't support cloning of objects by itself if you want to create some kind of automation consider using serialization.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-deep-clone-using-serializable.html

This type of copying is called deep cloning.

Answer (score 0):

By default in Java, the .clone() method doesn't actually make a "deep copy" of the object that you call it on. It's just going to give you a new reference variable and the object references in your new map are going to be copies of the references in your original map.

It's rather annoying, but if you need to clone certain objects in Java that haven't made a proper clone method, you need to just iterate through the object's data and place it into a new one (and make deep copies of objects where necessary).

So in your case, you can write loops that iterate through your map and make new references to new objects to be placed in your new map.